# How to call an unknown "onChange" function from other function

Tags: javascript, typo3, onchange

I'm sorry if the title is not too clear but I didn't know how to do it more precise.

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function p1() {
    document.getElementById('f1').value = 'Isaac';
}
function p2() {
    x=document.getElementById('f1');
    x.value += ' Newton';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" id="f1" name="f1" onChange="p2()">
<input type="text" id="f2" name="f2" onChange="p1()">
<input type="submit" value=">">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to show "Isaac Newton" in the f1 field when write something  in f2. I only can modify the p1 function. I don't know the name of the p1 functions, even it is changed every time the page is loaded.

Thanks.

---

Thanks for the answer. The real input fields are like this:

```
<input type="text" id="tceforms-textfield-4e20ac55d3700" class="formField tceforms-textfield" name="data[tx_oriconvocatorias_publicadas][NEW4e20ac55cdc8f][cnom]_hr" value="" style="width: 460px; " maxlength="255" onchange="typo3form.fieldGet('data[tx_oriconvocatorias_publicadas][NEW4e20ac55cdc8f][cnom]','required,trim,tx_oriconvocatorias_autoLlenar','',1,'');TBE_EDITOR.fieldChanged('tx_oriconvocatorias_publicadas','NEW4e20ac55cdc8f','cnom','data[tx_oriconvocatorias_publicadas][NEW4e20ac55cdc8f][cnom]');">
```

And I have 10 fields of different types: select, text and textarea.

Is there a way to load this dynamic code, from my onchange function?

---

I can access the name of the fields so I want to do something like:

```
function p1() {
code + name.Onchange;
}
```

It is possible? I don't know the correct syntax.

---

I also tried with the `focus(),click(),select() and blur()` methods, but they don't communicate Javascript that a change was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matters.

I used regEx to load the parameters and call the function p2 from inside the p1 function.

The call looks like this.

```
function p1(){ 
//... 
typo3form.fieldGet('data['+tconv+']['+idconv+']['+camconv[c]+']','','',1,'');
TBE_EDITOR.fieldChanged(tconv,idconv,camconv[c]); 
//... 
}
```

Where tconv, idconv, and camconv are the results of the regEx queries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the onChange event does not fire when you do `document.getElementById('f1').value = 'Isaac';`. So make these following changes and you should be good:

```
<input type="text" id="f1" name="f1">
<input type="text" id="f2" name="f2" onChange="p1();p2()">
```

Comment: Thanks @Ram. This is what I need to do, but I don't know the name of the function or its parameters. See the edited post. I need a dynamic way to load these functions.